# How to make memcached access time faster

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I have stored some value in the memcachedClient . when  i try to fetch it using get method it take some random time each time when execute Like 30 ms or 70 ms.  Here is the code how i am trying to measure the time

```
        long l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6;
        String[] keys = { ("key4") };
        l1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        client1.get(("key4"));
        l2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mLogger.info("total time taken in fetching from memcached=" + (l2 - l1));
        l4 = l2 - l1;
        l5 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Map<String, Object> map = client1.getBulk(keys);
        l6 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mLogger.info("total time taken in fetching from memcached using bulk="
                + (l6 - l5));
```

Here for l2-l1 i will get some measurable value like 70-80 ms. sometime 500 ms. i just wanted to reduce this time. please help.

Comment: 1. Likely a network issue. Get a faster network. 2. Run a MCD server on your local repeat the test.

Comment: I am currently just testing. I am not connected to any n/w . And how i'll get this mcd server. so i can run it and test.

Comment: huh... unless there is something really fishy a local memcached should be blazing fast sub 10ms. Anyway,  here to download MCD server http://memcached.org/

Comment: my memcached server is already running on the port 11211. I don't think thats the problem.